# Django - Unable to remain in the view assigned to LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL after redirecting to back page. I'm using custom AUTH_USER_MODEL

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm trying to get a custom user model named `(UserAccount)` working for logging in and logging out

My custom user account inherits these two classes

```
UserAccount(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin)
```

Used django.contrib.auth.views - LoginView and LogoutView in accounts app's urls.py file:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name="accounts/login.html"), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name="accounts/logout.html"), name='logout'),
    path('signup/', views.signup, name='signup'),
]
```

When I login, as per the setting `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`, I'm able to get redirected to the `landing_page`.

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'accounts.UserAccount'

LOGIN_URL = 'login'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'landing_page'

LOGIN_REQUIRED_IGNORE_VIEW_NAMES = [
    'login',
    'logout',
    'signup',
]
```

I've used the `django-login-required-middleware` and also included these two in my settings file:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'login_required', # along with others
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'login_required.middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware',    # along with others
]
```

**But whenever I hit back button on the browser from `landing_page`, it is again taking me back to login page, even after logging in. If I use the inbuilt user model `django.contrib.auth.models - User`, there's no problem Can someone please help resolve this authentication issue?**

Answer (score 0):

Somehow including this argument **`redirect_authenticated_user=True`** in the LoginView.as_view() answered the question

```
path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name="accounts/login.html", redirect_authenticated_user=True), name='login'),
```